# Does TFVC repo support passing PAT in the URL?

Tags: git, jenkins, tfs, azure-devops, tfvc

In VSTS, I can clone a Git Repo by including PAT in the URL so we can avoid passing username/password explicitly. For e.g. https://PAT@mytest.visualstudio.com/_git/my_Repo

I am curious if there is an option using TF VC where we I can get latest of a tfvc repo by adding PAT in the URL?

Note: I am trying to pass this URL (with PAT) to Jenkins 'Team Foundation Server Plugin' and does not want specifying the username password either manually or in Global configuration. [image: Jenkins Screenshot]

Comment: I may have asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56397103/3092298) just now. I was able to configure Jenkins to get the latest version by specifying "." for the username and my PAT in the password field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, TFVC does not support passing PAT in URL.

The URL for TFVC repo must with the format:

```
https://account.visualstudio.com
```

And for the credential (PAT) to provider to the TFVC repo, you can add in the user password option (as the example in below screen shot).

[image]

Comment: Thanks, may be I should opt for GIT repo's in VSTS/TFS while creating new projects?

Comment: Yeah, for VSTS/TFS git repo, you can passing PAT in git repo URL.