# Configure Jenkins CI build to use TFVC hosted in Azure DevOps

Tags: jenkins, azure-devops, continuous-integration, tfvc

We recently migrated from an on-premise TFS server to Azure DevOps. Our team uses TFVC for source control, and I'm getting the following exception when Jenkins polls for new check-ins:

> FATAL: This server requires federated authentication but no mechanism was available to handle it.
>   com.microsoft.tfs.core.exceptions.TFSFederatedAuthException: This server requires federated authentication but no mechanism was available to handle it.

Given the exception class name is `TFSFederatedAuthException` I suspect Azure is expecting some sort of OAuth integration, but Jenkins doesn't appear to support that for TFVC.

All I did was change the **Collection URL** for that Jenkins build to `https://dev.azure.com/MyCompany`. The **Project path** remains the same, and I verified this, because I was able to re-map all of my TFVC branches in Visual Studio by just pointing to the different collection URL and keeping the same project path. A screenshot of the Jenkins source control config is below:

[image: Screenshot of Jenkins build config screen.]

This Jenkins server is internal with no public facing IP address or host name.

**How can I allow Jenkins to poll a TFVC repository hosted in Azure DevOps in order to trigger a CI build in Jenkins?**

---

Why not use Azure pipelines? That's a much bigger migration effort at the moment, and I'm just trying to solve a short term problem.

Using Azure pipelines is my long term goal, but I need to figure out how our automated tests can use an Oracle database first, because all data is deleted before each test is executed using Selenium.

Comment: Generate a Personal Access Token in Azure DevOps. Then replace the user with "." and the password with the PAT. See if that works. `tf.exe` does take a special setting to pass in an OAuth token, but that's not the same as a PAT and it's not easy to obtain one ;).

Comment: Oh, wait a tick! I gave my PAT "full access" for permissions (not what I wanted) and now I at least got past the exception I posted about.

Comment: @jessehouwing: I need to tease out exactly which permissions Jenkins needs with the personal access token, but if you post your comment as an answer you'll get a +1, and I'll mark it as the answer. Thanks! That did the trick!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure DevOps uses OAuth to communicate by default, putting in your username and password won't work because of that. Instead, the trick is to generate a Personal Access Token (I suspect the `Code|Read+Write` scope should do it) and pass that in.

For the username pass in `.`, for the password your generated personal access token. Give the token a nice name so you know which one is about to expire once you get the email notification.

Comment: Do I need to store/provide token instead of password in Jenkins credentials / job configuration  ?

Comment: Yes put the token in the password field.